# Matlab calling superclass abstract constructor syntax seems strange

Tags: matlab, inheritance, constructor, super

I am trying to call a superclass constructor from the inheriting class. 
The official syntax in [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#brd2m9e-6) is:

> `obj = obj@SuperClass(ArgumentList);`

However the editor seems to warn that:

> the variable `obj` might be used before it is defined.

Moreover, if I try to run the code I get an error "The left operand of "@" must be the method name."

What could be wrong?

Comment: oh boy, that was annoying... my bug was that the constructor function name at the sub class had a typo. The editor nor the interpreter had detected that this was the problem.

Comment: Oops! That would do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this is a result of a typo of the sub-class constructor function name. Minimal reconstruction of the problem appears below:

```
classdef SuperDemo  < handle
    methods
        function obj = SuperDemo(opt)
            disp(['in super ', opt])
        end
    end
end

classdef SubDemo < SuperDemo
    methods
        function obj = SubDemoo(opt) % NOTICE THE TYPO SubDemoo 
            disp(['in sub ', opt])
            obj = obj@SuperDemo(opt);
        end
    end
end
```

If you call `s = SubDemo('hello')` you will get the error:

> Error using SubDemo Error: File: SubDemo.m Line: 5 Column: 19 "@"
>   Within a method, a superclass method of the same name is called by
>   saying method@superclass.  The left operand of "@" must be the method
>   name.

This error is misleading as the left operand is `obj` and not `SubDemo`.
The error message should have indicated that the construction function name `SubDemoo` is not the same as the class name `SubDemo`.